# how hide my 'DIV' element when click on any where on the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two HTML elements

```
<input class="button bttn-default" 
       type="button" 
       value="Preview" 
       ng-mouseover="showDropDown();" 
       ng-click="preview()"
       />

<div id="deviceList" 
     class="dropdown-content" 
     ng-hide="showChannelDropDown"
     >

    <a href="#" ng-click="hideDropDown('desktop')">Desktop</a><br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="hideDropDown('mobile')">Mobile</a><br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="hideDropDown('tablet')">Tablet</a><br/>
</div>
```

if I select the option a new window will open with the following code

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="dynamicWidgetDiv"></div>
</ div>
```

I want to hide the 'div' element with id 'deviceList', when I click anywhere on page except that element. my angularjs code as follows...

```
$scope.hideDropDown = function(v){ 
                         console.log(v);  
                         $scope.showChannelDropDown=true;
                         $scope.preview(v);
                      }

angular.element(document).on('click', function ($scope) {        
    alert("test");
    $scope.showChannelDropDown = true;
});
$scope.showChannelDropDown=true;           
$scope.showDropDown=function(){
    $scope.showChannelDropDown=false;
}
```

but its not working. the event

```
angular.element(document).on('click',function(){})
```

is getting called but the 'div' not hiding. This function should not be called when click on 'DIV' with id='outerdiv'.

could you give a solution...

Comment: This is because you are binding the events in javascript way, which is not executing angular scope digest cycle. In order to make your changes effective you will have to manually call the digest cycle of the scope using $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest().

Comment: where (in which function)  should I call it. could you suggest.

Comment: As per your current scenario you can call it inside function passed as an argument to angular.element(document).on('click',function(){}) or otherwise if you still face issues you can create a plnkr to repplicate your issue and I can go thro' that